# How to deduct chances in a game I created on Xcode for iPad

Tags: 2d-games, ipad-3

The subject of this game is the player must avoid the cans falling from the top. I want to
give the player 3 chances, this is my code:

```
_chancesCount = 0;
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_cola.frame, _cabbie.frame)) {
        _chancesCount += 1;
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_coffee.frame, _cabbie.frame)) {
        _chancesCount += 1;
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_tea.frame, _cabbie.frame)) {
        _chancesCount += 1;
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_soda.frame, _cabbie.frame)) {
    _chancesCount += 1;
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_beer.frame, _cabbie.frame)) {
        _chancesCount += 1;
    }
    if (_chancesCount == 3) {
        _currentState = _STATE_GAMEOVER;
    }
```

I setup a label to display how many chance the player have left
but it seems that whenever the can hit and leaves `_cabbie.frame(a yellow creature)`.
`chanceCounts` automatically turns back into `0`. so there must be 3 cans hitting cabbie at the same time to make the game over.

Comment: when you say that .chanceCounts automatically turns to 0, do you know for sure that it ever changed from 0. So, did it infact go 0, 1, 2, 3, 0... or, maybe it just stayed at 0.  ??

Comment: sorry, I haven't come back and check this website for weeks, yes, it did go like 0, 1, 2, 3, 0. chancesCount counted the exact amount of cans hit cabbie, it didn't add up, there must be three cans hitting cabbie in the same time to go gameOver